# Unable to import my locally developed Angular module into Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I'm looking at using [this Yeoman generator](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library) as a starter for a mini project containing a few reusable form components I can publish. The generator builds a module and an example component, directive, pipe and service configured for use ([you can see the template files for the generator here](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/tree/master/generators/app/templates)).

I then used `npm link` to allow me to install the generated project in my Angular app, which appears to work fine, as demonstrated below taken from the project's `node_modules` directory;

[image: Code imported into the angular app (<code>node_modules</code>)]

I have then imported the module into my module within my Angular app;

```
import { SampleModule } from 'my-test-library';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    MomentModule,
    SampleModule // <-- Imported Here
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: []
})
export class TasksModule { }
```

This module import causes the error `Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'SampleModule' imported by the module 'TasksModule'` and I cannot figure out why.

There are two things I notice when comparing the library I have imported with another third party library (e.g. `ng-bootstrap`)

1. As I have used `npm link` to import the library to allow me to test during development the entire folder structure has been imported (rather than just the `dist` directory. I assume this means the non-dist code is being imported by the `TasksModule`. If I attempt to import `my-test-library/dist` I get a module cannot be found error.
2. Unlike `ng-bootstrap` my library appears to be missing `*.metadata.json` files in the output.

My library's `tsconfig.json` file is as follows (unchanged from generator install)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, <-- Checked to ensure this was true
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Based on these items, or something else, what am I missing to get this working? Thanks!

**Edit: sample.*.d.ts files (as default after installation)**

```
// sample.component.d.ts
export declare class SampleComponent {
    constructor();
}

// sample.directive.d.ts
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
export declare class SampleDirective {
    private el;
    constructor(el: ElementRef);
}
```

**Edit 2**
So I tried symlinking the `dist` directory (`my-test-library/dist`) to the root of `node_modules` and importing the module from there and it worked fine.

1. Is there a way to, using `npm link`, only import the dist directory (at the root)?
2. I also don't understand why updating my original import to `import { SampleModule } from 'my-test-library/dist';` does not work?

Comment: Did you set your system.config file to map `'my-test-library'` to something?

Comment: Sorry, not sure which file you mean @echonax, my project does not have that file (It only has the root level files shown in the screenshot above)

Comment: so, may it be that you ran into this bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11639 which is talked about here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11438 ? if so, you may find a possible answer from 'Avien' on 16 sept. in the second link. I just speculate here, because there are so much possibilities. hope you get this worked out!

Comment: add your **sample.component.d.ts** , **sample.directive.d.ts** codes as well

Comment: Code added @Aravind

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to run watch on your code (something like "npm run watch")? That would give a better error message.

Assuming this is your index.ts file or similar to this (https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/blob/master/generators/app/templates/index.ts) What I am guessing is that either your module is not being exported properly or there are some circular dependencies among your exports. First, try changing the following four lines in your index.ts from:

```
export * from './src/sample.component';
export * from './src/sample.directive';
export * from './src/sample.pipe';
export * from './src/sample.service';
```

to

```
export {SampleComponent} from "./src/sample.component";
export {SampleDirective} from "./src/sample.directive";
export {SamplePipe} from "./src/sample.pipe";
export {SampleService} from "./src/sample.service";
```

If that doesnt work, then try changing the order of your exports. If still no luck, then please trying sharing the whole folder somewhere. Thanks,

Comment: Thanks - I tried updating the exports to no avail, but I did make at least a bit of a breakthrough (I edited the original post to reflect again).

Answer (score 0):

In your file listing I do not see a `sample.module.ts`, only a `component`, `directive`, `pipe` and `service`. If you do not have a file with the `@ngModule` decorator which imports/provides these, then you are not truly importing a `SampleModule`.

the file should look something like this:

**sample.modeule.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SampleDirective } from './sample.directive';
import { SampleComponent } from '../sample.component';
import { SamplePipe } from './sample.pipe';
import { SampleService } from './sample.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ],
  declarations: [
    SampleDirective,
    SampleComponent,
    SamplePipe
  ],
  providers:[SampleService],
  exports: [
    SampleDirective,
    SampleComponent,
    SamplePipe
  ]
})
export class DayModule { }
```

Comment: Sorry, but the template project defines the module in `index.ts` as [here](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/blob/master/generators/app/templates/index.ts)